# QR Code with empty/black center square

Tags: image, qr-code

I want to print a qr code with its middle portion blacked out and then print variable data on the black square (which would be none of QR code's business).

How can I achieve that? One way could be while generating QR, I define my timing pattern or some configuration to be fixed as this centered black square.

I'll be using my own app to decode it, so I would know the configuration while decoding as well.

Comment: If you write your own decoder, then you should be able to write your own “encoder” as well, right?

Comment: CBore, yes I will have my own decoder. I just want to look for provisions in existing QR code (read zxing) to enable this use case.

Comment: Can I not try to create a custom QR code with my own decoder in place, the data is all around the center logo image and I could still use the lowest level of error correction to make sure that I could encode as much data as possible? Any pointers, how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of a 2D barcode with a "free" center area is certainly plausible--Snapcodes are one example, and Denso Wave (who invented QR) have a proprietary form called Frame QR.

That said, what you create should not be called a QR code, and decoders will not be compatible. The ones you see in the wild with artistic centers are using error correction to achieve the effect.